# Prove that $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x^p}dx = O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for every $p > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The question is to prove that $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x^p}dx = O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

for every $p > 0$ when $n \to +\infty$.

I'm trying to integrate by parts but don't understand what can I do with $\sin(nx)$ in this terms. What other way can I do to prove this equality?

Comment: I have a feeling the substitution $z=nx$ might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $x = t/n$ and integrating once by parts
$$
\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{x^p}dx =n^{p - 1} \int_n^{+\infty}  {\frac{{\sin t}}{{t^p }}dt}  = \frac{{\cos n}}{n} - pn^{p - 1} \int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\cos t}}{{t^{p + 1} }}dt} .
$$
Now note that
$$
\left| {\int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\cos t}}{{t^{p + 1} }}dt} } \right| \le \int_n^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{t^{p + 1} }}dt}  = \frac{1}{{pn^p }}
$$
for any $p>0$.

Comment: Seems like in this case we couln't get $O(\frac{1}{n})$, isn't it?

Comment: @Someone Indeed it would give us $O(1)$ if we estimated before integrating by parts.

Comment: @user Try it and see what you get.

Comment: @Someone, $\cos n / n = O(1 / n)$.

Comment: @vonbrand That was an answer to a now deleted comment by "user" not a remark about my derivation.